# Google Chrome with Selenium

Tags: python, linux, selenium

How to use `selenium` with `google chrome` to scrape websites?

And what about `virtualenv`?  Is it required? Why to use it/why not to use `virtualenv`?

#Install Google Chrome

```
wget -c wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
apt-get -f install
```

#Install Selenium

```
apt-get install python-dev python-pip
pip install selenium
```

#selenium_scrape.py

Simple script to check if its working

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

#Command

```
python selenium_scrape.py
```

#Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selenium_scrape.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/platform/chrome')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chrome' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f88e9347190>> ignored
```

#The full script

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
 
def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver
 
def lookup(driver, query):
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    try:
        box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.NAME, "q")))
        button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.NAME, "btnK")))
        box.send_keys(query)
        button.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Box or Button not found in google.com")
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()
    lookup(driver, "Selenium")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: You now have a python syntax error, your code is not indented properly.

Comment: The code in the try block needs to be indented the same way as the code in the except block.

Comment: What are you offering a bounty for after accepting an answer already?

Comment: This was blatantly a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/); I somewhat arbitrarily rolled it back to the point where it was when the bounty was offered. At any rate, the bit about an `IndentationError` is clearly unrelated to the question that was actually being asked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is (at the moment) about an indentation error. This can be easily fixed:

```
def lookup(driver, query):
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    try:
        box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.NAME, "q")))
        button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.NAME, "btnK")))
        box.send_keys(query)
        button.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Box or Button not found in google.com")
```

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that you cannot use a packaged Chrome browser; you need a special driver... chromedriver.

Get the current latest version here:
[Chromedriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.21/)

Now you have 2 options, either to move the downloaded chromedriver so it is always accessible (option 1), or to define in your script how to access it.

#### Option 1: move it into path

Then move it so it is accessible when you use `webdriver.Chrome()`:

```
sudo mv /path/to/download/chromedriver /usr/bin
```

Also set it to be allowed to be executed:

```
chmod a+x /usr/binchromedriver
```

#### Option 2: do not move it into path

Or you can define a path

```
import os
chr = "/Users/you/Downloads/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chr
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

Comment: Ok, so I dont need to install Google Chrome at all..? I just need this chromedriver you posted?

Comment: @clarkk Yep, indeed.

Comment: I have now downloaded the driver, unzipped it to `/usr/bin` and runned the script again but get this `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver` I have remembered `chmod a+x /usr/bin/chromedriver`

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps try `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

Comment: Then check it is the same version as you downloaded with the URL (you might have to download another version by changing it in the link). Check version using `chromium-browser -version`. If this helps, I'll update the answer.

Comment: `apt-get install chromium-browser` `E: Package 'chromium-browser' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Try to find it using a search: `apt-cache search chromium`

Comment: have now installed chromium with `apt-get install chromium` but still get this error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable`

Comment: Did you try both option 1 and option 2?

Comment: Also, it is usually a lot easier to get Firefox to run. Is there a specific reason to use Chrome?

Comment: No specific reason why I use Chrome.. Do you have a link how to install Firefox on Debian?

Comment: Have updated my question.. I'm now trying with Firefox instead.. Have installed Firefox but get an error when running the script

Comment: There is now an indentation error: the part between `try:` and `except:` should be 4 spaces to the right.

Comment: Thanks.. It works! :) but how do I send the HTML output to stdout?

Comment: HTML can be accessed from `driver.page_source`. Then you can just `print`. Glad it helped :)

Comment: When I do `print driver.page_source` it looks like it prints the first page and not the search results

Answer (score 2):

(Note: the original question was about Chrome, so my answer is about Chrome, not Firefox).

For me it works if I just extract the chromedriver into the same folder where the script is.

Then I run it as this

```
Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x16 &
echo 'Starting the test'
PATH=$PATH:. python selenimum_scrape.py
```

This will start the Xvfb and include the cromedriver into `PATH`.

And the modified version of your which works for me:

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# comment this out to run on the real display
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':99'

def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver

def lookup(driver, query):
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    try:
        box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.NAME, "q")))
        # once we type the query, this button disappears
        # button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        #     (By.NAME, "btnK")))
        box.send_keys(query)
        button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.NAME, "btnG")))
        button.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Box or Button not found in google.com")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()
    lookup(driver, "Selenium")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work? What is the error you have?

Comment: @clarkk I updated my answer to work with `Xvfb`. Start the `Xvfb` before running the script, I used port :99. In the script itself add `os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':99'` to run it on the virtual display and comment out this line to see the browser GUI.